# Eventlistener stops working after few clicks with no errors in console

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener

I'm making simple to-do list for my portfolio. It allows user to create new tasks, remove them or mark them as done with crossing effect

It seems to be working, but when you add few new tasks something happens with eventlistener that is responsible for crossing the task done. From this moment some tasks can be crossed out, some not. I tried to fix it but honestly I have no idea why this happens. Any help appreciated

```
document.getElementById('addTask').addEventListener('click', newTask)

function newTask() {

    const taskText = document.getElementById('taskInput').value;
    let parentTask = document.querySelector(".singleTask");
    let childTask = parentTask.cloneNode(true);
    document.getElementById('taskList').appendChild(childTask);
    childTask.querySelector("p").innerHTML = taskText;
    childTask.classList.remove('crossedOut');
    childTask.classList.remove('invisible');
    childTask.style.opacity = '1';
    reload();
}


const removeIcons = document.querySelectorAll('[bin]');
removeIcons.forEach(e => e.addEventListener("click", () => removeTask(e)));

function removeTask(e) {
    e.parentNode.parentNode.style.opacity = '0';
    setTimeout(() => {
        e.parentNode.parentNode.classList.add('invisible')
    }, 350)

}


const tasks = document.querySelectorAll('div.singleTask');
tasks.forEach(e => e.addEventListener("click", () => crossOut(e)));

function crossOut(e) {
    e.classList.toggle('crossedOut')


}

function reload() {
    const removeIcons = document.querySelectorAll('[bin]');
    removeIcons.forEach(e => e.addEventListener("click", () => removeTask(e)));
    const tasks = document.querySelectorAll('div.singleTask');
    tasks.forEach(e => e.addEventListener("click", () => crossOut(e)));
}
```

```
<div class="plannerBox  shadow-lg">
   <p class="plannerTitle">Daily Planner</p>
   <div class="newTaskContainer">
      <input type="text" id="taskInput" class="form-control" value="What to do next?">
      <div class="addTask" id="addTask">
         <p>
         <div class="a_demo_three">
            Add task
         </div>
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="taskContainer" id="taskList">
      <div class="singleTask">
         <p>Read a book</p>
         <div class="removeTask">
            <i class="far fa-trash-alt" bin></i>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="singleTask">
         <p>Metting with team</p>
         <div class="removeTask">
            <i class="far fa-trash-alt" bin></i>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="singleTask">
         <p>Kill yourself</p>
         <div class="removeTask">
            <i class="far fa-trash-alt" bin></i>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

If you want to see it live: http://www.blackravenstudio.net/javascript/  'Plan you day'
Keep in mind this portfolio is still in progress :)

Comment: Every time you add a task you add a new event listener, this not not related to your question but still a problem.

Comment: Can't reproduce problem on live example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your reload function you are adding a new event listener to every task once a new one is added.

```
function reload() {
  const removeIcons = document.querySelectorAll('[bin]');
  removeIcons.forEach(e => e.addEventListener("click", () => removeTask(e)));
  const tasks = document.querySelectorAll('div.singleTask');
  tasks.forEach(e => e.addEventListener("click", () => crossOut(e)));
}
```

So when you add 3 tasks this are the number of listeners that each will have (aussuming that 3 are present when the page loads):

4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1

This issue in combination with your `crossOut` function

```
function crossOut(e) {
    e.classList.toggle('crossedOut') 
}
```

Means that only tasks with an odd number of listeners will be able to be crossed out. (because toggling a class an even number of times will leave it unchanged)
To fix this you need to change your reload function.

```
// changed name from reload to addTaskEventListners
function addTaskEventListners(task) {
  task.addEventListener("click", () => crossOut(task)):
  const removeIcon = task.querySelector('[bin]');
  removeIcon.addEventListener("click", () => removeTask(task));
}
```

and call it in your `newTask` function like so `addTaskEventListners(childTask)`. You then also need to change your `removeTask` function slightly like this:

```
function removeTask(e) {
    // e is now the task element itself and not the remove button.
    e.style.opacity = '0';
    setTimeout(() => {
        e.parentNode.parentNode.classList.add('invisible')
    }, 350)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add "1" it works.
If you add "1" and "2", "2" works.
If you add "1", "2", and "3", "1" and "3" works.

So basically only the one that is added before the last entry doesn't work.

I'm not sure it will be helpful but, try using this:

```
// put crossOut function between { .. }
tasks.forEach(e => e.addEventListener("click", () => {crossOut(e)}));
```

Comment: I am very much sure that this won't help, see my answer for an explanation.

Comment: But it easy enough to try.